# Need expert opinion on Data Sharing between components in angular

Tags: angular, service, angular7, conceptual, angular7-router

As per my understanding of data communication between components, we can do it by @input(), @output(), and by making one common broadcasting service.

I believe that service is the best way to do it as  @input and @output depending upon various conditions like

1. folder structure should be in a parent-child mode like a nested structure.
2. We can not use @output for components which are handling by  as we never find its selector.
3. Also we cant use @input & @output for non-parent/ child components.

So better is to make a common service for communication so that we can even communicate between the same level component (not parent-child) and also a child-parent component.

So please I need all of your opinions, Am I right here or any better way ??

Comment: I think you should check out the documentation for component interaction here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction. There are a couple of ways for components to communicate with each other and which way you choose depends on your requirement.

For instance, if you have a form that repeats in different parts of your application. It would be best to use ````@Input````, ````@Output```` for this case as you can easily pass in any data to the child component (form) from the parent through ````@Input```` and on submitting the form you can emit an event to the parent component.

Comment: Also, the folder structure does not play a part in parent-child interaction. When a component makes use of another component within it, it becomes the parent as it has a wider scope and the child component may a part of that scope. So you can have the components in your folder structure however you want and just import the child component to the parent using the correct import statements.

Answer (score 1):

Akshay you are right. It actually depends on the situation.

1. When you parent child relationship using @Input and @Output decorator is good choice.
2. Avoid using @Input when you have a deep nested object and also want to detect changes. Angular doesn't detect changes using @Input decorator with deep nested object. In this case service is best.
3. When you want to manipulate data, you can use service. So that the another component gets data in the way it wants.
4. Also you can use the concept of Redux using NGRX store to share anywhere in the app.
5. Another approch is to use @ViewChild decorator.

By practice you will learn where to use which approch.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no relationship (parent-child or child-parent) between 2 components then you can not share data using @input or @output between two components.
For such case, you have use common service, calling function of common service, in this function "$next" the service variable and in 2nd component where you want to use that just write "$subscribe" of that common service variable.

```
// calling common service method and pass data to used by component 2 from component 1
this.commonService.method(data);

// common service variable
private variable1 = new Subject<any>();
variable1$ = this.variable1.asObservable();

// common service method
method(data: any) {
    this.variable1.next(data);
}



// passing and calling itself in component 2
 this.commonService.variable1$.subscribe(data => {
        if (data) {
           // use data send from component 1
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Condition you should consider: Is component reusable ?

My advice is don’t start implementing your application until you’ve identified reusable components.

In the process or identification think how component is going to be used ?.
Start with ()Output if gets complicated to track communication switch to service.

If component is going to be used by only one parent component use ()Output there is no need for service.

Also, avoid using @Input when you have a deep nested object and also want to detect changes.